# Uncaught ReferenceError: snaptr is not defined with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager on Ecommerce site. When adding cart, I see the error log.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: snaptr is not defined

Screenshots:

[image]

And

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: When and how snaptr is initialized? Is it also created by a GTM Custom HTML tag, or by a script outside of GTM?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I also aware that Facebook Pixel or Snapchat can cause that kind of issue.

Comment: It would be important to know this, as most probably the snaptr is not initialized at all, or you try to use it before it gets initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is literally named in the error message - you are calling a function that does not exist.

Tracking tags like these are usually made up of two separate parts - one "setup" tag that downloads the respective tracking library, and one (or more) tags that do the actual tracking by calling library functions.

If you look at a screenshot from their [documentation](https://businesshelp.snapchat.com/en-US/article/snap-pixel-about) you can see that there is a code block to load the tracking library:

[image: Snapchat tracking pixel code]

The bit starting with `(function(..` up until `scevent.min.js');` is where the code is loaded that defines the tracking function. If this is not there, `snaptr` will be undefined, just as stated in your message.

The usual way to do this is via a [tag sequence](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/understanding-tag-sequencing-in-google-tag-manager/) in GTM. This makes sure that the tag that loads the library is always executed before the tracking functions are called. This works basically the same for Facebook tags.